# querying my database using cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, android-sqlite

I have a database set up and I know I am inserting to it correctly.  I am, however, having difficulty returning any data from it through a query.  This is my main class and database helper class.

```
public class DBTesterActivity extends Activity {

MyDBAdapter db;
Cursor cursor;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Item item1;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    db = new MyDBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    db.insertEntry(item1 = new Item("Bathtub", "Bathroom", "Typical", "Clean", "fill, wash", "Round, deep", "Bathroom", "Toilet, Bathroom", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    //this.populateDatabase();
    //Cursor entryCursor = db.getAllEntries();
    item1 = db.getEntry(1);
    Log.i("db", item1.toString());
}
```

and my database adapter class here...

```
public class MyDBAdapter {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase.db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//main table columns
public static final String KEY_ITEM              = "itemName";
public static final String KEY_GROUP             = "itemGroup";
public static final String ITEM_CLASSIFICATION   = "classification";
public static final String KEY_USE               = "use";
public static final String KEY_ACTION            = "action";
public static final String KEY_PROPERTIES        = "properties";
public static final String KEY_ASSOCIATION       = "association";
public static final String KEY_IMG_ID            = "imgId";

// The index (key) column name for use in where clauses.
public static final String KEY_ID="_id";

// The name and column index of each column in your database.
public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
public static final int GROUP_COLUMN = 2;
public static final int CLASSIFICATION_COLUMN = 3;
public static final int USE_COLUMN = 4;
public static final int ACTION_COLUMN = 5;
public static final int PROPERTIES_COLUMN = 6;
public static final int ASSOCIATION_COLUMN = 7;
public static final int IMG_ID_COLUMN = 8;
// TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.

// SQL Statement to create a new database.
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + 
        DATABASE_TABLE + " (" 
        + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
        + KEY_ITEM + " TEXT, " 
        + KEY_GROUP + " TEXT, " 
        + ITEM_CLASSIFICATION + " TEXT, " 
        + KEY_USE + " TEXT, " 
        + KEY_ACTION + " TEXT, " 
        + KEY_PROPERTIES + " TEXT, " 
        + KEY_ASSOCIATION + " TEXT, " 
        + KEY_IMG_ID + " INTEGER);";

// Variable to hold the database instance
private SQLiteDatabase db;
// Context of the application using the database.
private final Context context;
// Database open/upgrade helper
private myDbHelper dbHelper;

public MyDBAdapter(Context _context) {
    context = _context;
    dbHelper = new myDbHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public MyDBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    try {  
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    db.close();
}

public void insertEntry(Item item) {
    // TODO: Create a new ContentValues to represent my row
    // and insert it into the database.
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ITEM, item.get_item_name());
    values.put(KEY_GROUP, item.get_group());
    values.put(ITEM_CLASSIFICATION, item.get_item_classification());
    values.put(KEY_USE, item.get_use());
    values.put(KEY_ACTION, item.get_action());
    values.put(KEY_PROPERTIES, item.get_properties());
    values.put(KEY_ASSOCIATION, item.get_association());
    values.put(KEY_IMG_ID, item.get_img_id());

    // insert row to table
    try{
        db.insertOrThrow(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
        Log.i("success", "insert was successful");
    }catch (Exception e){Log.w("insertFail", "insert failed: " + e.toString());}


}
  public Item getEntry(long _rowIndex) {
// TODO: Return a cursor to a row from the database and
// use the values to populate an instance of MyObject
  SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

  Cursor cursor = db.query(false, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ID,
          KEY_ITEM, KEY_GROUP, ITEM_CLASSIFICATION, KEY_USE, KEY_ACTION, KEY_PROPERTIES, KEY_ASSOCIATION, KEY_IMG_ID}, KEY_ID + "=?",
          new String[] { String.valueOf(_rowIndex) }, null, null, null, null);
  if (cursor != null)
      cursor.moveToFirst();

  Item item = new Item(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
          cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8),  Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(9)));
  // return contact
  return item;
```

}

I am getting these in my logCat ----  Bad request for field slot 0,9. numRows = 1, numColumns = 9
and                             ----  java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 9 failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get all columns so i think more clearer way is tu use `rawQuery` method.
You can do it like this:

```
SELECT_QUERY = "Select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE + " where " + KEY_ID + " = ?";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(SELECT_QUERY, new String[] {String.valueOf(_rowIndex)});
if (c.getCount() > 0 && c.moveToFirst()) {
   Item item = new Item(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
      cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8));
}
```

**Note:** But, you didn't meant what kind of problem, any error?

**Update:**

Your problem is the most likely this:

```
Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(9))
```

Numbering of columns start from **0** not from **1** so:

**_id** - 0

**_itemGroup** - 1

**classification** - 2

**use** - 3

**action** - 4

**properties** - 5

**association** - 6

**imgId** - 7

**properties** - 8

So you tried to get non existing column. Repair it and then it should works.

Comment: _rowIndex is an integer for which row I want to return in the query, I cant put that into an array of type string ... String[]

Comment: sry wait i update it. i forgot to cast it to String. check update.

Comment: Is the _id automatically the first column then?  it is automatically assigned unless specified correct?  So if you query the very first piece of data you can get is the _id column?

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help.  I have got the query working and can now get a row from my DB for use.  Your advice was very helpful.